# Inserting arrays from textbox into Database using Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have my data submitted through jquery form

```
"<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td><input name='subjects[]' class='form-control' disabled value='" + name + "'></td><td><input class='form-control' disabled value='" + staff + "'></td><td><input type='hidden' name='staffs[]' class='form-control' value='" + staff_id + "'></td></tr>"
```

In my Controller (SubjectsController.php), I have

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $subjects = array();
    $subjects = $request->subjects;
    $staff = $request->staffs;


    $subjectSet = [];
    foreach($subjects as $subject){
        $subjectSet[] = [
            'schoolclass_id' => $request->schoolclass_id,
            'name' => $subject,
            'staff_id' => $staff
        ];
    }

    DB::table('subjects')->insert($subjectSet);
```

When I submit this, I keep getting **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: `$request->subjects` is not an array. Try `dd($request->subjects)` and check what it contains

Comment: Disabled values do not get passed from the form. Make it `readonly` instead. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled

Comment: To avoid this kind of issue, you could do `$subjects = $request->input("subjects", []);`, which would set `$subjects` to an empty array if it was `null`. You tried to do this with `$subjects = [];`, but promptly overrode that.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, That returned null

Comment: @aynber, thank you! That worked.